# How do I parse attestationVersion and keymasterVersion in Android key attestation?

Tags: android, security, android-keystore

When performing [Key Attestation in Android](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/keystore/attestation), I'm getting a certificate with the following first 4 values in the `1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.1.17` x509v3 extension:

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 304 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :64
    7:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  ENUMERATED        :02
   10:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :64
   13:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  ENUMERATED        :02
 ... snip ...
```

These correspond to [this ASN.1 schema](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/keystore/attestation#schema):

```
KeyDescription ::= SEQUENCE {
  attestationVersion         INTEGER, # KM2 value is 1. KM3 value is 2. KM4 value is 3.
  attestationSecurityLevel   SecurityLevel,
  keymasterVersion           INTEGER,
  keymasterSecurityLevel     SecurityLevel,
 ... snip ...
}
```

Both the `attestationVersion` and `keymasterVersion` are given as `0x64` (integer value 100). I was expecting a value of `1`, `2`, or `3`.

Can anyone explain to me what these `0x64` values represent?

======== Edit 1 =========

In case it's useful to someone, here is a full hexdump of that extension:

```
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
```

======== Edit 2 =========

I found [this line](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:cts/tests/security/src/android/keystore/cts/Attestation.java;l=52?q=keymasterVersion&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject) in the AOSP code, indicating that 100 is `KM_VERSION_KEYMINT_1`.

Searching online, I can find very few references to Keymint. Does anyone know what Keymint is?

Comment: Are you sure it is 0x64?  Based on your posted snippet lit looks more like 64 = 0x40. For easy ASN-1 decoding I would recommend to use https://lapo.it/asn1js/

Comment: @Robert - Yes. It's 100. I tried using that tool that you linked. It also gives 100: `INTEGER 100`.

Comment: I have updated the question to include the full extension data, in case that's useful to someone to see the context.

Comment: Looking at the code you have found the documentation is wrong for a long time as it mentions everything but values like 1, 2 or 3. Regarding keyMint there is a complete description what such a device is supposed to provide: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:hardware/interfaces/security/keymint/aidl/android/hardware/security/keymint/IKeyMintDevice.aidl?q=IKeyMintDevice.aidl May be KeyMint is the Rust reimplementation of Keymaster?